# unity parse wait for response

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am making a game in Unity.
Is is possible to wait for a response from Parse.com ? I know i am doing a FirstAsync but i need to wait for it.
I tried with t.Wait() but it does nothing.

```
public int getNumberOfCoins()
{

    string id = getFacebokId ();
    string score = "0";

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("UserNumber").WhereEqualTo ("fbid",id);

    query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        t.Wait();
        ParseObject items = t.Result;
        score = items.Get<string>("coins");
    });


    return int.Parse(score);
}
```

Does anybody know if you can hold the return of this function until request to Parse is done ?

Comment: Have you tried query.FirstAsync().Wait().ContinueWith(...);

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip but this is not working. I can not do that. I can only query.FirstAsync.ContinueWith(...).Wait(); which it is making Unity unresponsive.

Comment: Since you said this makes Unity unresponsive, I think you are calling getNumberOfCoins() from the UI thread... Are you updating the UI with the score that you are returning from this method?

Comment: Yes , that is what i am doing. How can i make that possible ?

Comment: I am not sure how you are updating the UI... I will post an answer where I solved a similar problem

Comment: I have not actually used Parse.com, But I have a solution that uses SynchronizationContext... I can suggest you the solution... but, before that can you check whether you can access SynchronizationContext.Current from within this method?

Comment: No, i don't have access to SynchronizationContext. If i can't make Wait() happen maybe i will use my own server/php script to sync the data. But this will not be a great solution.

Comment: Since you cannot use SynchronizationContext, see if you can access the UIThreadDispatcher. Instead of blocking with a Wait, you can let it continue async... And once the score is computed (at the end of the ContinueWith block) you can update the UI with something like... UIThreadDispatcher.Instance.InvokeOrEnqueueOnMainThread(() => UpdateTheUI(score));... Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
await query.FirstAsync()
```

And maybe read up on [Async and await.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: This is not ok. I am getting unexpected symbol errors